# Restricting user to enter specific values in input field angular 12

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, validation, input-field

I have a input field

```
<input type="text" [value]='$' (keydown)="handleKeyDown($event)">
```

Dollar sign is prefilled.
How can I restrict user to enter only the pattern '$1,000.00' (US dollars with $ prefix);

So far , I was able to restrict the user from entering values other than `$ , . and numbers` But, they can enter consecutive commas, dollar symbol and dots.

```
handleKeyDown(event:any){
    let key = event.keyCode || event.which;
    if((key>=48 && key<=57) || (key===52 || key===190 || key===188 || key===8)){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
 }
```

To restirct that I am using a Regex and regex works fine. But, I am not sure in which event I should use the `Regex.test()`, because if I use it in `keyup()` event the character is already populated in the text filed, there is no point in doing `event.preventDefault()`.
If I do it in `keydown()` event then I can not extract the complete value of the text field before the `keydown()` event is finished. And I should also accomodate copy and paste in the field.

There is no privision for `blur` event, I need to check this during the user input only, and avoid it from appearing in the text filed.

Is there anyway to achieve this? Would you suggest an easier way using the reactive form input field?

Comment: Do you need the input field to contain the $ sign? I would make a small "hack" to look like there is a $ at the beginning, like using a <div> right next to the input with the $ sign. And if you need the $ to be on the input value, after he triggers the action i would check if the value he uses is a valid number and then add the $ as the first char of the string.

Comment: Ya I can keep a $ placeholder and make $ appear after user enters the vaild value.

Comment: I looked up how ngx mask does it and it's a pain to do in one method https://github.com/JsDaddy/ngx-mask/blob/develop/projects/ngx-mask-lib/src/lib/mask.directive.ts#L357

Comment: Oh man, thats huge.

Answer (score 1):

Like Sebastian Ciocarlan said you can remove the $ from the input and just allow numbers and commas if you don't need to store the $.

But instead of using a `<div>` you can use `matPrefix` from angular material (if you use it) to add $ in front of your input (or `matSuffix` if you want to put it at the end).

You can see an exemple here : https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#prefix--suffix

Comment: I can not keep the div/matprefix. I need to have $ inside text field. Now, what I have done is if user enters the consecutive , . or $ I am checking it against Regex and removing the entered character and make input field border red for a second to indicate its an invalid entry.